# How do I use the 1st character match using ^ in GAS?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I am trying to match the 1st character using regex in GAS. When I insert ^, the code doesn't work.If my id is "DEL", then I need words starting with "D", when id is "DEL" then all words strarting with "DEL".

`````
function getAirportMatch(e) {
 
  
  var airportlist = "`DELHI VIDP, MINDELIHM HEID, DELHI VIDD, LIHELD HDEL";
  var id = "DEL";
var regExp = new RegExp("^(?:"+id+")","gm"); // "i" is for case insensitive
var airport = regExp.exec(airportlist);
Logger.log(airport);````
`````

Comment: What exactly is the data? Please edit your question to show the string you’re attempting to match.

Comment: So you want to match “DELHI VIDP” and “DELHI VIDD”?

Answer (score 0):

To match terms starting with something, use word boundary `\b` and matching everything up to the next comma (or end, which ever comes first):

```
"\b"+id+"[^,]*"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to see which airport names start with `DEL` you can simply make use of the `startsWith` method:

```
var airportlist = "DELHI VIDP, MINDELIHM HEID, DELHI VIDD, LIHELD HDEL";
var airportarray = airportlist.split(', ');
var id = "DEL";
airportarray.forEach(e => {if (e.startsWith(id.toString()))console.log(e)})
```

The snippet above creates an array with all the airport names and then checks if any of them start with the `id` you have supplied.

#### Reference

- [String.prototype.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith).